# $E=\{x:f(x)=0\}$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

How to prove that

$E_1=\{x:f(x)=0\}$
and $E_2=\{x:f(x)>0\}$ are measurable sets.Here $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb C$.

I know this may be a very basic question but as a new in Measure Theory I am not able to find the proof. Please help.

Comment: There is still missing context.  What is $X$?  Some sort of set with a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets?  What are the assumptions on $f$?

Comment: X is same what you said and f is a complex measurable function.This is mentioned in Rudin's Real and complex Analysis book page no. 12.

Comment: It is important that you specify hypotheses in your problem.  In particular here, it is important that $f$ is measurable.  So you know that $f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable for each open $V\subseteq \mathbb C$.  You can write $\{0\}$ and $\{z\in\mathbb C:z>0\}$ as countable intersections of open sets.

Comment: Assume there exists a nonmeasurable subset $E\subset X$. Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\in E,\\1&\text{if }x\notin E\end{cases}$. Then $E_1=E$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some assumptions you need for your question to make some sense. What is $X$? What is the measure defined in $X$?

For the sake of giving you an answer I will assume $f$ is a continuous function and $X$ is a measure space whose $\sigma$-algebra contains the borel sets (that means, every borel set is measurable). Another thing, if $f$ is a complex-valued function then saying $f(x)>0$ is nonsense, so I will assume you wanted to say that the real part of $f(x)$ is positive.

Under these assumptions, you can have the following answer. I will expect you to modify your question though.

Assuming $f$ is continuous then $E_1=f^{-1}(\{ 0 \}$ is the inverse image of the closed set $\{ 0 \}$ which means it is closed, hence a Borel set, hence measurable.

In the same fashion, note that the region in $\mathbb{C}$ of all complex numbers with strictly positive real part is an open set. If you prove this then $E_2$  can be seen as the inverse image under f of an open set, hence it Is open,  hence borel, hence measurable.

Comment: $X$ needn't have a measure, just a sigma-algebra of subsets.  $f$ is not assumed continuous, just measurable, meaning that for every open set $V\subseteq \mathbb C$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is in the sigma-algebra.  (I agree that the question should include this context, but the OP said in a comment that $f$ is a measurable function, and gave a book reference for the definitions being used.)  I don't think it is safe to assume that $z>0$ for a complex number $z$ means that the real part is strictly positive; it often means also that the imaginary part is $0$, hence $\{z\in\mathbb C:z>0\}$ is not open.

Comment: We only need to use the definition of measurable given above, because both $\{0\}$ and $\{z\in\mathbb C:z>0\}$ are countable intersections of open sets.  (Also, $X$ is not assumed to have a topology here, so the notions of "the Borel sets" and continuity of $f$ may not be defined.)

Comment: (I meant to say in my first comment, "I don't think it is safe to assume that $z>0$ for a complex number $z$ means *only* that the real part is strictly positive..." It often means that in addition to $\mathrm{Im}(z)=0$.)